# does the scraper only crawls the url from the domain defined in start_url?

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to get all the links from a site page. However, it seems like its not able to get the page out of domain specified in start_url.
Here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from mp3.items import *
import re

class Mp3Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mp3"
    start_urls = ['http://mp3skull.com']
    # allowed_domains= ['mp3skull.com']
    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'mp3/\w+']), callback = 'parse_post',
        follow= True)
    ]

    def parse_post(self, response):
        item = PostItem()           
        item['url'] = response.url
        if item['url'][0].endswith('.mp3'):
            return item
```

I want to get the urls with mp3 extention but the urls are of different domains.
One of the url is http://uhmp3.com/user-mp3-to/8-all-about-that-bass-by-meghan-trainor.mp3
What is the best way to get all the urls within the domain?

Answer (score 1):

Your rule

`Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'mp3/\w+']), callback = 'parse_post',
        follow= True)`

only allows links whose absolute url contains 'mp3/' to be extracted. That's why you cannot get other domains extracted.

You can add a regex in `allow` to include other links, for example:

`Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'mp3/\w+', r'.mp3$']), callback = 'parse_post',
        follow= True)`

Comment: I want to get the urls with mp3 extention but the urls are of different domains. One of the url is http://uhmp3.com/user-mp3-to/8-all-about-that-bass-by-meghan-trainor.mp3

Comment: Since urls with a different domain usually don't contain 'mp3/', they are not extracted with your current rule, thus not parsed by the `parse_post` method. You have to include other kinds of urls in your rule to have them extracted and passed to your `parse_post` method.